# Rails 4.2: rendering collection_check_boxes in Ajax response results in non-html_safe content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Rails 4.2.  I have a "new projects" page on which there is a form to create a new project.  There is also a second form on the page that allows the user to add users to the project through Ajax.  The Ajax is working, but I am having issues rendering the response correctly.

The "new project" form shows the available users as a list of checkboxes, created by this snippet:

```
<div id="disclosed_users_check_box_list">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :disclosed_user_ids, User.order(:first_name, :last_name), :id, :name_with_job_title do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %><br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The "new user" form uses Ajax to create a new user and then responds with this JS:

```
$("#disclosed_users_check_box_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(collection_check_boxes(:project, :disclosed_user_ids, User.order(:first_name, :last_name), :id, :name_with_job_title) { |b| "#{b.check_box} #{b.label}<br>" }).html_safe %>");
```

The problem I am having is that the `.html_safe` at the end does not appear to be doing anything.  When the response is rendered, I see the raw HTML appear on the "new project" page, instead of actual checkboxes and labels.

Any ideas of where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!  I was putting the `.html_safe` in the wrong place.  Here is what worked:

```
$("#disclosed_users_check_box_list").html("<%= j(collection_check_boxes(:project, :disclosed_user_ids, User.order(:first_name, :last_name), :id, :name_with_job_title){ |b| "#{b.check_box} #{b.label}<br>".html_safe }) %>");
```